# Trigger the native contacts ui in phonegap [ios]

Tags: ios, cordova, contacts, phonegap-plugins

I've been looking through the documentation for the Contacts API and there are ways to retrieve and save contacts to display them on your own UI.

But is there any way to trigger the native contacts to display your address book?

Something similar to the SMS plugin which pops up the native sms composer within the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the exact same thing and came across this http://fqnow.com/phonegap-contact-picker/. Here's the Javascript code, all you need to do is:

```
function contactChooser(){
  var options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.fields = ["displayName", "name", "emails", "phoneNumbers"];
  navigator.contacts.chooseContact( onSuccess, options);
}
function onSuccess(id, contact){
  alert(id);
  alert(contact);
}
```